# Test if my application will be suspended on playstore

Tags: android

can someone tell me how can I test my apk , I want to avoid suspension so where can i test if it is all ok , Is there some webpage or something that i can see if my app meets all the criteriums, because i have tried once and my account is now suspended

Comment: Well... what sneaky things are you trying to do with your app?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There is no automated tool or website that can definitively tell you whether your application violates the developer policies and will be taken down or issued a strike.

You will need to review the [Developer Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/) yourself and come to a decision as to whether your app follows the policies or not.