# Is addJavascriptInterface with untrusted code still an issue with minSdkVersion > 17?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-security

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9095419), you should not use `addJavascriptInterface` with untrusted code (by "untrusted" they mean anything not bundled with your app) and if you do so it may cause the app to be removed from the Play Store. My understanding is that this is due to security vulnerabilities around JavaScript being able to call methods using reflection. However these were remediated in API 17 as any method called from JavaScript must be annotated with `@JavascriptInterface`. My app has minSdkVersion of 21, so I feel this policy is not applicable. I am only exposing some basic functions which display toast messages.

I have not yet tried to publish the code which uses `addJavascriptInterface` as it's still being tested. However, as [Google doesn't provide any way to check your app before you get to publication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41124621/191761), I am not sure if this code will be blocked.

As an alternative I am looking into using `createWebMessageChannel` as an alternative to `addJavascriptInterface`, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753104/how-do-you-use-webmessageport-as-an-alternative-to-addjavascriptinterface). While it is ostensibly more secure, it doesn't support API < 23 (so for me that would be API 21-22 which couldn't use this solution), and it also seems unnecessarily complicated for what I'm trying to do.

For apps with minSdkVersion > 17, can we still expect the app to be blocked from Play Store due to the above policy?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you take the necessary safety precautions. Be careful that you set the webview interface in Proguard.

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```